# how do i create Layout (image / button / emoticons ) for Chat apllication like this?

Tags: android, layout, chat

I've just created a chat app for android,
I got a problem to create a place for sticker,emoticons,and images which is limited by an appearing tab while click the button as the picture bellow..
http://mydistrosport.com/gab.jpg

perhaps anyone of you can help, where can i get the link to solve this case ?

Thanks..
newbie..

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768930/implementations-of-emoji-emoticon-view-keyboard-layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you should use `Slidingdrawer` .
you will be having nice samples from following links

1. http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/03/29/widget-slidingdrawer-top-to-bottom/
2. http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/
3. http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-slidingdrawer-top-down-style/

Comment: Ok..thanks for your reply...nice link..
but i've one question more..if i add tab include slidingdrawer..can i place the xml layout to inside sliding drawer??
*sorry for my bad english..

Comment: yeah... you can include any layout.. what you like.. if you are satisfied with this answer .. accept or up-vote it.